# For Flashpoint... can you "share" the victim POI marker?

Tags: flash-point

Like, lets say for example,
Orange firefighter had to end their turn with a victim POI marker right in front of the door leading to the outside. The player going next has their yellow firefighter right outside that door. 
O | y  <- makeshift diagram where 0 is orange and y is the yellow one that is outside the building.

Can the yellow firefighter move into the building on the square with the orange firefighter, take the victim POI marker and move back outside with the POI marker?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

You can consider the cost in dealing with victims having to do with **moving** them, not so much carrying and holding onto them.  So if one firefighter moves a victim to square, there is no cost for picking up or dropping the victim, simply a cost to transfer the victim from one location to another.  With this in mind, you can walk up to a square where a firefighter has just moved a victim and continue to move that victim into a different square, assuming you still have enough action points to bear the load.

Comment: I completely agree